# How to use dockerfile agent in Jenkins DSL script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need to back-port the Jenkins pipeline to old Jenkins job format with DSL. I'm stuck at the agent section:

```
agent {
    dockerfile {
        label 'buildDockerNode'
        dir 'devops/k8s/build'
    }
}
```

How can I use this method on old Jenkins? In old Jenkins job DSL I only see the `label` configuration for the corresponding Pipeline syntax.
Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By using the pipelineJob property, your agent will be configured by the pipelineDSL. No need to define it again in jobDSL https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob

To ease the transformation to jobDSL, I would recommend to use the jenkins-pipelayer library it abstracts jobDSL for you and you can use properties files to configure your pipeline. the docs is here: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-pipelayer/blob/master/USAGE.md#template-engine

Comment: I just back-ported the job to old system. BTW, I found the solution below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with `buildInDocker` wrapper:

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-wrappers-buildInDocker

```
job('example-2') {
    wrappers {
        buildInDocker {
            dockerfile()
            volume('/dev/urandom', '/dev/random')
            verbose()
        }
    }
}
```